# Showing a composition is in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f$ be a smooth increasing function passing through the origin with $|f(x)| \leq C_1(1+|x|)$. Define $F(r) = \int_0^r f(s)\;ds$ and $F^*(t) = \sup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}tr - F(r).$ Note that $F^*(f(x)) = xf(x) - F(x)$.

If $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ for $\Omega$ bounded, then $F^*(f(u)) \in L^2(\Omega)$.

How do I prove this? I can't show that $F(u) \in L^2$, only that it is in $L^1$ using the growth condition.

Comment: Do you consider a finite measure space?

Comment: @saz $\Omega$ is bounded if that's what you mean

Comment: But what about the measure? Is $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and the integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes @saz, sorry, it's just the usual Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @saz I read this: "it follows that $F^*(f(u)) \in L^1$. Since the growth condition holds, we have that $F^*(f(u)) \in L^2$.

Comment: No, the growth condition holds for $f$ and not for $F^{\ast}$! See the answer below; as long as $u \notin L^4$, we cannot expext $F^{\ast}(f(u)) \in L^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is not true. Consider

$$f(x) := x,$$

then $F(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$, and therefore

$$F^{\ast}(f(u)) = u \cdot f(u) - F(u) = u \cdot u - \frac{u^2}{2} = \frac{u^2}{2}.$$

This shows that $F^{\ast}(f(u)) \in L^1$, but not necessarily $F^{\ast}(f(u)) \in L^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give a look at this: http://www.emis.de/journals/EJDE/2002/45/hachimi.pdf
on page 3, the displayed equation after (2.2). It contradicts this.

Comment: There $\beta$ is my $f$, $\Psi$ is $F$ and $\Psi^*$ is $F^*$

Comment: @LapLace Looks in fact like a contradiction. But unfortunately there is nothing I can do about it.